# Node.JS - Program Terminates Before Receiving Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, webdriver-io

I'm utilizing WebdriverIO v4 to create HTML reports of various tests passing/failing. I gather the results of the tests via multiple event listeners (ex. this.on('test:start'), this.on('suite:end'), etc.). The final event is this.on('end'), which is called when all of the tests have completed execution. It is here were the test results are sorted based on which Operating System it was run on, Browser, etc.

It seems that the problem is that my program terminates before allowing the function to complete or receiving a callback from the function.

Here is the gist of my code:

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
    //Censored keys for security
    accessKeyId: '*****',
    secretAccessKey: '*****',
    region: 'us-west-2'
});

let s3 = new aws.S3({
    apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
});

/*
*
* Here is where the program generates HTML files
*
*/

//The key and data fields are not actually asterisks, this is just to show that key and data fields are initialized at this point
let key = "****"
let data = "****"

s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'html',
    Key: key,
    Body: data
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
    if (data) {
        console.log("Success: ", data.Location);
    }
}).on('httpUploadProgress', event => {
    console.log(`Uploaded ${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
});
```

When the tests are run, the results are displayed, and then the program terminates.  The program does not wait for the callback to return, so no error or success message is displayed.  The files are not uploaded to S3.

I know that the `s3.upload()` works because if I run the code earlier in the project with dummy data, the upload succeeds.  But at the end of my project, the program terminates before the upload finishes.

How can I fix this issue?  How can I guarantee that the files are uploaded to S3 before the program terminates?  How can I see the callback before termination?  Thank you!

Comment: Last time you posted this you had an error, is that error resolved or is this the same question just reworded? [Referencing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601046/node-js-aws-program-terminates-before-upload-to-s3-bucket-completes)

Comment: The npm error was caused by tests failing.  This error does not occur when all tests pass.  Despite all tests passing or some tests failing, nothing is uploaded to S3 and no callback is returned in the program.  There are no success or error messages.

Comment: Did you try adding a callback line after the console.log lines inside s3.upload? Add `callback(err)` inside the if(err), and add `callback(null, data)` inside the if(data)

Comment: Thanks for your help Deiv.  I really appreciate it.  I added the `callback` lines like you suggested, but this didn't solve the problem either.  Where do you think the problem lies?  Is webdriverIO the problem, is the s3 package the problem, or something else?

Comment: No problem. You can try make the s3.upload before the webdriver call, and see if it works? Or, surround the web driver call in a try/catch block

Comment: @Brian which point in wdio you are calling this upload code. I too have my own HTML result generator and initially faced the same problem. i call the report generation function as part of `onComplete` hook.

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan Hi, which version of WDIO are you using? I am using v4, and my custom HTML reporter requires @wdio/reporter. Your project was also terminating before allowing the project to upload to S3?

Comment: @Brian .. I am in v4. I am not using `@wdio/reporter`. I build the HTML using the `json` file that is created by `wdio-json-reporter` library. It was terminating before creating the HTML file initially but after i converted my custom function to return a PROMISE and using `async/await` in the `onComplete` hook, it works fine. WDIO waits still the HTML is created. NOPE, i am not uploading it to S3.
Please look at the last comment of mine in Deiv ans of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601046/node-js-aws-program-terminates-before-upload-to-s3-bucket-completes. Let me know if you need help.